# how to find a viewpoint in polygon(maybe concave polygon) that the viewPoint can most edge of the polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygon

as the title. In a room (convex polygon or non-convex), how to find a point when i stand the point ,i can see all the walls(edges) of the room?

Comment: In general, there is no such point.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial problem; for most polygons, there is no point from which all edges (or all corners) can be seen.

There is ample literature on the topic; you can search for the art gallery problem, or the museum problem

Art Gallery Problem on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem)